# How to get an email from SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

This is bugging me. Something so simple and it does not work. What could I be doing wrong?

Here is the code I am using ...

```
    string strSQL = "SELECT ac.ContactEmail AS fldEmail FROM vwApprenticeshipContactDetails ac WHERE (ac.ApprenticeshipID = @ApprenticeshipID)";
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(strSQL, cnn);
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@ApprenticeshipID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = wsAppID;
    Object fldEmail = cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
```

Believe it or not, the above returns what looks like an array when I debug and look at the value of 'fldEmail'. In otherwords it's empty, nothing or null (cannot tell as the output window shows an array). I have run this directly in SQL server and I get the email showing fine. Could the '@' character inside the database field be causing something here?

The email I expected back is 'g.somebody@domain.com.au', which to me looks ok.

**UPDATE**

I replaced the ContactEmail field above, with another column name from the database and it comes back fine. Not sure why emails are an issue. The datatype by the way here is `VARCHAR(50)`.

**UPDATE**

In debug mode I noticed it returns `system.DBNull` data type (and digging deeper it returns empty), but why? I ran the exact same query with the correct parameter in SQL server and I get a email showing. Strange

Thanks

Comment: Hint! Debug cmd2 just before executing and see the value for CommandText. Try to run that query string in database.

Comment: @voddy Nothing unusual there. The SQL shown is the same as above.

Comment: Ya strange. Try to select * and see if Email address returns.

Comment: Could it because I am returning this from a View and not an actual table in the database?

Comment: If you're getting bad values from a view, a logical place to start debugging is the view itself ...

Comment: @EdmundSchweppe Thanks, but I just did that and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it!

For some reason (and I am a noob when it comes to email objects in C#), but an ExecuteScalar is not properly populating as it was not "read" first. What I mean by this is that when I changed ExecuteScalar to an SqlReader, it worked because I am "forcing" the read of the SQL before testing it.

So my code looks now like this and it returns an email!

```
strSQL = @"SELECT TOP 1 ContactEmail FROM vwApprenticeshipContactDetails WHERE ApprenticeshipID = @ApprenticeshipID";
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(strSQL, cnn);
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@ApprenticeshipID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = wsAppID;
using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
{
  string fldEmail = "support@domain.com.au";   //this is as a default in case the sql above does not return a value
  while (rdr.Read())
  {
    fldEmail = rdr.GetSqlValue(0).ToString();
  }
}
```

I was avoiding SqlReader initially because I thought they were specifically designed for when reading in more than one row of data. In my case I know the parameter given only returns one row or nothing at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At the first change select to top 1 for performance reason.

```
string strSQL = "SELECT Top 1 ac.ContactEmail AS fldEmail FROM ...
```

If you dont have any result in query, you will get null value as result.

You can check how many records returned by query in sql server profiler.

Also you can check your connection string to make sure are you connected to correct database.

Comment: Thanks, but I did all that. In fact I changed the ContactEmail to some other column (like another text field such as StudentName) and lo-and-behold the student name came back. It seems, I am sure that if the Email contains the '@' character (and in my case I have emails with full stops as well - ie: sir.rowdy@gmail.com), that it plays up with asp or something. But you're right about the TOP 1. I added that as well. Again same problem. The email value I expect is "g.rody@domain.com.au". That email looks ok to me.